# SQL Server: Find words in string that don't exist in dictionary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##tableA;
CREATE TABLE ##tableA (id int,keywords VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO ##tableA (id,keywords) VALUES
    (1,'apple,orange,potato'),
    (2,'I typed a sentence here because I can''t follow directions.'),
    (3,'potato and apple');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##dictionary;
CREATE TABLE ##dictionary (id int,keyword VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO ##dictionary (id,keyword) VALUES
    (1,'apple'),
    (2,'orange'),
    (3,'lemon'),
    (4,'potato');
```

We have users entering keywords into the keyword column in tableA.  I want return the id of any record that contains a word not in ##dictionary.

In the case above:

```
- id 1 would not be returned because each comma separated keyword is found in the dictionary
- id 2 would be returned because it contains words that are not in the dictionary
- id 3 would be returned because it contains the word "and", which is not in the dictionary
```

The ideal situation I think would somehow break up the keywords column from ##tableA into individual keywords, then check each of them against the keyword column in ##dictionary.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Should this really be based on temporary tables, or you are using them just as an example?

Comment: What if you have hyphenated words in the dictionary, and individual keywords separated by hyphen in `Table A`?

Comment: The temp tables are just as an example, so that someone could run that code and generate a working example more easily.  Hyphenated words could be in the dictionary, but for the purposes of this question we're going to require comma delimiters for tableA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an inline approach

**Example**

```
Select Distinct A.*
 From  ##tableA A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.KeyWords,',',' '),' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Left Join ##dictionary C on B.RetVal=C.keyword
 Where C.keyWord is null
```

**Returns**

```
id  keywords
2   I typed a sentence here because I can't follow directions.
3   potato and apple
```

> **Just another BRUTE FORCE OPTION - Just for fun**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = (Select * From ##tableA For XML Raw )
Select @S = replace(@S,keyword,'') From  ##dictionary

Select id = B.i.value('@id', 'int')
 From  (Select x = Cast(@S as xml).query('.')) as A 
 Cross Apply x.nodes('row') AS B(i)
 Where B.i.value('@keywords', 'varchar(max)') like '%[a-z]%'
```

Comment: This works well too...  It's a bit hard for me to parse though... Does this assume the keyword list is comma-separated with no space?

Comment: @Lawson Option 1 will make the comma delimited to space delimited.   Option 2 does not care.

Comment: @Lawson  I see you are on 2016,   String_split is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Under SQL Server 2017, you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql):

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    ##tableA
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(keywords, ' ') splitBySpace
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(splitBySpace.value, ',') splitBySpaceOrComma
WHERE
    splitBySpaceOrComma.value NOT IN (SELECT keyword FROM ##dictionary)
GROUP BY
    id;
```

Comment: SQL Server 2016, too, and Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Apparently we have SQL Server 2016, but our compatibility level is set to 110 (instead of 130.) Working with the dba to get that changed for my database.  This looks like it should do what I'm wanting though, and it's elegant.

Comment: If your dictionary is large, use `WHERE NOT EXISTS ()` instead of `WHERE NOT IN ()` -- it'll run way faster.

Comment: Luckily in my case my dictionary will probably be 30-40 allowed keywords

Comment: @DaveCullum Assuming `keyword` will actually be NOT NULL in production, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS mean the same thing and will likely produce very similar query plans.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

[Splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

you can split lines by delimiter then use the result to match against the dictionary.  like this:

```
SELECT t.keywords FROM ##tablea t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(t.keywords, ' and ', ',')) new(kwds)
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(new.kwds, ',') s
WHERE s.item NOT IN (SELECT keyword FROM ##dictionary)
```

Comment: This doesn't really give an answer, it's more of a comment

Comment: I often prefer to give direction rather than complete worked-out answers.  When you give direction, the requester gets a chance to learn while solving the problem.  It's the "give a man a fish" vs "teach a man to fish" philosophy

Comment: DelimitedSplit8K is only available in SQL Server 2016 or newer.  While we're using 2016, the compatibility mode is set to 2014.  I'm working on getting that changed.

Comment: @Lawson DelimitedSplit8k works on SQL Server 2008+. You're thinking of `STRING_SPLIT`. The article linked was even initially written in 2011, way before SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  The DelimitedSplit8k function has to be created first.  We'll see if the DBAs will give me permission to create functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.*
from ##tableA t
cross join (
    select max(case when id = 1 then keyword end) firstKeyword,
           max(case when id = 2 then keyword end) secondKeyword,
           max(case when id = 3 then keyword end) thirdKeyword,
           max(case when id = 4 then keyword end) fourthKeyword
    from ##dictionary
) d where
  len(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(keywords, firstKeyword, ''), secondKeyword, ''), thirdKeyword, ''), fourthKeyword, ''), ' ', ''), ',', '')) > 0
```

First, you need to pivot your data from `##dictionary`, then you can replace your keywords with `''` as well as spaces and commas, and see in the end if the are any characters left.

Comment: this doesn't return the third row from the sample data